# Adding Commas to form fields with equation using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, formatting, field

Hello currently having issue with getting my form to work. The goal is to input values in the first 3 fields and get a total while at the same time displaying commas in the fields. The total however is coming up NaN I assume its due to the commas. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".input").keyup(function(){
           var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
           var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
           var val3 = +$(".value3").val();
           $("#result").val(val1*val2*val3);
    });
 });
 $(document).on('keyup', '.comma', function() {
     var x = $(this).val();
     $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input value1 comma" >
<input type="text" class="input value2 comma">
<input type="text" class="input value3 comma">
<input type="text" class="comma" disabled="disabled" id="result">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the commas are in your textbox values, the code can no longer cast them as integers. A simple solve would be to strip all commas when multiplying.

Try removing commas from your `val` variables with a simple `.replace()`, like so:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".input").keyup(function(){
           var val1 = +$(".value1").val().replace(/,/g,"");
           var val2 = +$(".value2").val().replace(/,/g,"");
           var val3 = +$(".value3").val().replace(/,/g,"");
           $("#result").val(val1*val2*val3);
    });
 });
 $(document).on('keyup', '.comma', function() {
     var x = $(this).val();
     $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input value1 comma" >
<input type="text" class="input value2 comma">
<input type="text" class="input value3 comma">
<input type="text" class="comma" disabled="disabled" id="result">
```

Comment: Thank You Santi this worked like a charmed now the only thing to fix the the result field where the comma doesn't show thank you very much for your help